# linking django templates with the Div Navbar

Tags: html, css, django

```
base    # base.html
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href={%url "joins.views.home"%}>Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href={%url "joins.views.share"%}>Share</a></li>
                  <li><a href={%url "joins.views.contact"%}>Contact</a></li>
                </ul>


    #urls
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^home/$', 'joins.views.home', name='home'),
        url(r'^contact/$', 'joins.views.contact', name='contact'),
        url(r'^(?P<ref_id>.*)$', 'joins.views.share', name='share'),
        # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),are
```

that is what I have but get a : NoReverseMatch at /base.html

Reverse for 'joins.views.share' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P.*)$']

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a keyword argument for ref_id, since there's one in the urls.py definition. Here it is with ref_id being the number 1:

```
<li><a href={%url "joins.views.share" ref_id=1%}>Share</a></li>
```